# NSMutableDictionary taking as value NSArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, arc4random

hi i am new in objective C and i have hard time with array indexing

I need to create a NSMutableDictionary which contains 5 rgb colours.
Each colour will contain the 3 components being generated randomly and the alpha value will be fixed to 1.0.
This should be inside a for loop.

by the end i need to have

1. key: first_col    **_________**   value: 0.13, 0.75, 0.91, 1.0
2. key: second_col   **______**   value: 0.25, 0.06, 0.48, 1.0
3. key: third_col    **________**   value: 0.86, 0.12, 0.55, 1.0
4. key:    **_______________**   value:
5. key:    **_______________**   value:

thank you

Comment: wouldnt it be easier to have an array with UIColor instead?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What, specifically, are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this answer..

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictonary;
        NSMutableArray *temp=[NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            dictonary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [dictonary setObject:[self getColor:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"color%d",i]];
            [temp addObject:dictonary];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",temp);

    }
    -(UIColor *)getColor:(NSInteger)index
    {
        UIColor *color;
        color=[self returnColor:index ];
        return color;
    }
    -(UIColor *)returnColor:(int)passedIndex
    {


       CGFloat red = arc4random()%255;
       CGFloat green =arc4random()%255;
       CGFloat blue = arc4random()%255;

        UIColor *color;
        switch (passedIndex) {
            case 0:
                color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255) green:(green/255) blue:(blue/255) alpha:1.0];
                break;
            case 1:
                color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255) green:(green/255) blue:(blue/255) alpha:1.0];
                break;
            case 2:
                color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255) green:(green/255) blue:(blue/255) alpha:1.0];
                break;
            case 3:
                color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255) green:(green/255) blue:(blue/255) alpha:1.0];
                break;
            case 4:
                color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255) green:(green/255) blue:(blue/255) alpha:1.0];
                break;
            case 5:
                color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255) green:(green/255) blue:(blue/255) alpha:1.0];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return  color;
    }
```

Comment: you should select only one answer

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
NSDictionary * colorsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1.0],@"color1",
                             [UIColor colorWithRed:(260/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(105/255.0) alpha:1.0],@"color2",
                             [UIColor colorWithRed:(106/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(205/255.0) alpha:1.0],@"color2",
                             [UIColor colorWithRed:(10/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(55/255.0) alpha:1.0],@"color3",
                             nil];
```

Comment: thanks  @iRaki. This works perfectly. In case i want to add to the dictionary an array *col_components (for the general case) how it should be [CGFloat col_components],@"color1"